# Link Order ID with User ID and get user name Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to get user name of user created offer based on seller id. I have 2 tables in database:
First table User

> User
> |
> | - id
> | - name

And second table Orders:

> Orders
> |
> | - id
> | - seller (User id)

What i want to achieve is to get user name based on seller id of order

Here is my Controller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
Use Auth;
Use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Session;

class MarketplaceController extends Controller

public function index(){

        $offers = DB::table('order')->paginate(30);

        return view(
            'marketplace.index',
            [
                'title'              => 'Browse offers',
                'offers'             => $offers,
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

And here is my blade.php

```
       @foreach($offers as $offer)
                <hr>

                <div data-link="/offer/{{ $offer->id }}" class="col-12 offer">
                    <div class="col-3">{{ $offer->title }}</div>
                    <div class="col-3">{{ $offer->description }}</div>
                    <div class="col-3">{{ $offer->status }}</div>
                    <div class="col-1">{{ $offer->price }}zł</div>
                    <div class="col-2">Sprzedawca:{{ $offer->seller }}</div>
                </div>
        @endforeach

        <div class="col-6 offset-3" id="pagination">

            {{ $offers->links() }}
        
        </div>
```

I am using Laravel 7.21.0
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use link between table User an Orders
in your function index try this:

```
public function index(){

    $offers = DB::table('order')
     ->join('users','user.id','=','order.seller ')
      ->select('user.name','order.*')
      ->paginate(30);

    return view('marketplace.index',
        [
            'title'              => 'Browse offers',
            'offers'             => $offers,
        ]
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Order` model you will add

```
public function seller() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'seller');
}
```

in your view you will use `seller()` relation to access your `User` model data

```
@foreach($offers as $offer)
      ...

      <div class="col-2">Sprzedawca:{{ $offer->seller->name }}</div>
             
      ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where exactly should i put it in my code, this seller() function? I am beginner at laravel, and I'm still learning

Comment: In your `Order` model in your `app` directory